# How to search file *contents* (grep/ag/rg) using FZF?

Tags: grep

When I run a project-wide (multi-file) search through [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), the results are flooded with lines whose *filepath* matches the query, crowding out the more relevant results where the file *contents* matched.

For example, running the [Ag example from the wiki](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples#searching-file-contents),

```
ag --nobreak --nonumbers --noheading . | fzf
```

I'll query for `search` and get something like this,

```
  plugin/keybindings.vim:cnoremap <expr> <C-Y> refract#if_incsearch("\<C-L>", "\<C-Y>")
  plugin/keybindings.vim:cmap            <C-P> <Plug>(refract_incsearch_prev)
  plugin/coherent.vim:set incsearch
  plugin/coherent.vim:setg tags+=./tags;~  " search for tags recursively upwards until ~
  plugin/search.vim:" use it for tab-completion instead depending on context of cmdline
  plugin/search.vim:  autocmd User Hint,listical_next,listical_prev Latitude
  plugin/search.vim:  autocmd User Grepper call hint#prepare_highlights()
  plugin/search.vim:let g:fzf_colors =
  plugin/search.vim:" let g:grepper =
  plugin/search.vim:\   <q-args>,
  plugin/search.vim:\   <bang>0)
  plugin/search.vim:augroup END
  plugin/search.vim:  autocmd!
  plugin/search.vim:
  plugin/search.vim:
  plugin/search.vim:
  plugin/search.vim:
> plugin/search.vim:
  41/517
> search
```

What am I doing wrong? When I run a similar Ag query without FZF, I only get the results where my query occurred in the file contents (which is what I want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was misunderstanding the interaction between ag and fzf, thinking the query I typed was somehow passed through ag before piping to fzf. In retrospect, this was a silly mistake to make, since the filtering is exactly what fzf does, and ag is being used simply as a way to generate tons of meaningful lines.

To get what I wanted out of this, I looked at the format of the lines that ag generated, e.g.

```
plugin/coherent.vim:set incsearch
```

Tell fzf to treat `:` as the field delimiter and that it should restrict the scope of its search to fields 2, 3, 4,...

```
ag --nobreak --nonumbers --noheading . | fzf --delimiter=: --nth=2..
```

This will break if any of the processed files contain a `:` in their filename, but that's something I don't expect to happen too often.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There is a typo in "delimeter", it should be "delimiter" instead :)

Comment: @ZheLi good catch. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a ripgrep script, this is what I came up with:

```bash
FZF_EDITOR="gvim"

# Fuzzy Ripgrep Ignoring-case
frgi() {
  local result
  IFS=$'\n' result="$(rg -i --line-number "$@" | fzf --no-sort --tac --delimiter=: --nth=2..)"

  local filename
  local lineno
  local _
  if [[ -n "$result" ]]
  then
    IFS=':' read -r filename lineno _ <<< "$result"
    # Vim can accept line-number with +99
    # But if your editor cannot, then you had better remove the + argument
    verbosely "$FZF_EDITOR" +"$lineno" "$filename"
  fi
}
```